# Can iterator.next() remove elements from the source? (Java)

Tags: java, iterator

There is a Java function

```
public <T> void batchWrite(Iterable<T> source, int number)
```

that writes a large number of items in a time-efficient way.

I want to use this `batchWrite()` on a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` that may be written to while `batchWrite()` works. And I want `batchWrite()` to delete the items that it takes from the queue.

I can write an iterator (and wrap it into an `Iterable`) that will delete the returned items:

```
class IteratorThatRemovesReturnedValues<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    Queue<T> queue;
    IteratorThatRemovesReturnedValues(Queue<T> q) { queue = q; }
    boolean hasNext() { return queue.peek() != null; }
    T next() { return queue.poll(); }
}
```

The question is: ***will not that be an abuse of the concept?***

The description of `remove()` says:
*The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this (`remove()`) method.* 
This may be read in either way: a particular implementation of `Iterator` may either be or not be allowed to define what happens when the underlying wait-free queue is modified in some specific way.

***Will removing returned elements from the underlying queue contradict the iterator's contract?***

(The alternative is to `poll()` an amount of items into an auxiliary `ArrayList` and invoke `batchWrite()` on that list.)

EDIT The other side of this question: ***can an iterator be backed by a pipe?***

Comment: IMO you can do same with a `LinkedList` without implementing Iterator returning the removed item...

Comment: Yes, it would be abused. An iterator's next() method is not supposed to remove. Why don't you just use the queue's iterator and call remove() on it?

Comment: I would say that a fully compliant Iterator shouldn't remove elements when remove isn't called. Imagine you create two Iterators for the same collection, and want to iterate over both; *boom*.

The thing with contracts is that you can expect certain behaviour. If your Iterator is really called `IteratorThatRemovesReturnedValues`, and you document it's behaviour in a way that EVERYBODY knows what to expect, I wouldn't worry about the official, intended contract.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're not considering the (many) caveats of the `Iterator#remove()` method, the behavior of an iterator, according to the contract, is simple. Particularly, it does not say anything about the underlying implementation.

A side note: Historically, `Iterator` was associated with the iteration over a `Collection`, but this may just be a remedy to the legacy `Enumeration` class. There are many `Iterator` implementations that are **not** related to a collection. (For example, [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and many more). Nowadays, an `Iterator` is often really not much more than an *"abstract source of things that allows you to query whether there are more things available"*.

But strictly speaking, your implementation already does **not** obey the contract. The documentation of the [`Iterator#next()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) says:

> Throws:
>
> **NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements**

This is not the case for you. Your implementation would simply return `null` here. Of course, this could easily be alleviated by replacing the `poll()` call with a call to `remove()`, which would conveniently throw an `NoSuchElementException`, but I guess that would contradict your current goals.

I think that the cructial point is that your implementation of the `next()` method has a side-effect that will be **visible to the outside world**. One example was already given in the comments: When you create two of these iterator instances, then both may behave according to their contract, but the behavior of both together may differ from what one would expect.

The latter only refers to **single-threaded** usage. When two threads are independently using these iterators, then an interweaving of calls to `hasNext()` and `next()` may induce a race condition. (Even more when two threads are using a single iterator, but this is the case for *all* iterators, because they usually are stateful anyhow).

---

The bottom line is: Although some details of the intended usage are still not clear (particularly regarding the question of how exactly the iterator is used in the `batchWrite` method, and how the multiple threads are supposed to interact here), this way of implementing it is likely to break sooner or later, and the bugs will be hard to detect and reproduce. I'd recommend to consider alternative implementations here.